# "start" command not working ?? Why?

Tags: php, apache, cmd

I used this code and it's works fine when I run php script on local host

```
<?php
echo system('dir');
?>
```

But when I replace the command as this

```
<?php
 system('start');
?>
```

### It doesn't work for me. But when I executed this script through cmd its also works fine. I want to know how can i run the cmd on the system when i run php script on local host. **Please explain** what is wrong here and is there any system security problem is here.

### Additional Info

### i save it on foo.php file. It's working when i running c:\apache\htdocs\test\php foo.php [ENTER KEY] it's open the new window. But during running the same script on server .. I met with problem. While on the server If i running the dir command. I am able to echo all the dir present there.

### IMP POINT

Server is running on my system. Any server setting changes required then please help and suggest.

Comment: start makes a new cmd and immediately exits, You wont have access to the child after its been spawned

Comment: add cmd /c  before start and try

Comment: @user1283633: If `dir` works fine, there is obviously a shell around that, already. I.e. it is run with `cmd /c` already.

Comment: nothing happened ... Mr. user1283633

Comment: Just to understand it, i know what you are doing, but, exactly,  what is the result you are trying to obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons:

1. The `start` command is not in the path for the user executing the PHP script.
2. The user executing the PHP script does not have access right to execute the `start` command.

For the first one, you can give the full path to `start` in your script.

For the second part, you need to contact the server administrator to request execute permissions for the user that normally runs PHP scripts.

If you are running the script from a browser, the user is usually the same process that is running your webserver (although on some servers its a different user).  Check with your server admin or host.

Comment: I am working on windows .. and start can be executed in any of the directory. I do not get your explanation. Some how you get me an idea. Please clear more if you could.

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the `start` command; please check with your server administrator for more information. It is possible the user that the server is running as does not have access to the command. Just because "you" can execute it doesn't mean a server process can. Otherwise anyone can write a script to `format c` and have you click on a link to execute it.

Comment: sir as i told u. the code it running fine for me. as i save it on foo.php file. It's working when i running c:\apache\htdocs\test\php foo.php [ENTER KEY] it's open the new window. But during running the same script on server .. I met with problem. While on the server If i running the dir command. I am able to echo all the dir present there.

Comment: and server is running on my system.

Comment: When you type it _yourself_ on the command line, the program is running with your permissions, when you _click on it in the browser_, it is executing with the permissions of the _web server_, which is **not** the same user. This is the basic problem.

Comment: Ok. Then How Could I resolved it. How could I am able to give permission to the web server user. May be it's security reason. But I want to do this for a testing purpose.